# How to set a seed for hyperparameter tuning jobs in AWS SageMaker for reproductibility

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, random-seed, hyperparameters

I would like to run REPRODUCTIBLE experiments on AWS SageMaker.  Hyper-parameter tuning jobs are source of randomness either with Bayesian or Random strategies: each time you run them with the same data you obtain slightly different results since the search in the hyper-parameter space is pseudo-random. The variance of the result is significative as explained here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-automatic-model-tuning-now-supports-random-search-and-hyperparameter-scaling/

Is there an way of setting a seed for these jobs? From the doc it does not seem to: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/tuner.html

The only way I see to mitigate the effect of randomness is to run enough training jobs per hyperparameter tuning jobs.